# Why is Google OAuth2 returning java.io.IOException?

Tags: google-oauth, oltu

Within the last few weeks a suite of our applications using Google's Oauth2 authentication system and the Apache Oltu library have stopped working.

All attempts to register or log in via Google meet with the same error:

```
Login/registration action failed: java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
```

This was all working fine recently and we have made no code or application changes in the intervening time.

Has something changed at the Google end which is causing all these requests to fail?

I do no seem to have any logging or information  available from my Google developer console.
Within my application the log entries indicate an attempt to authenticate which does not succeed.

The code which is now failing, which used to succeed is:

```
            // obtain a AuthRequest message to be sent to the OpenID provider
        OAuthClientRequest oauthRequest = OAuthClientRequest
                .authorizationLocation(discovery.getAuthzEndpoint())
                .setClientId(Oauth2Util.getClientId())
                .setRedirectURI(responseURL)
                .setResponseType(ResponseType.CODE.toString())
                .setScope(GOOGLE_SCOPE)
                .setState(state)
                .buildQueryMessage();

        response.sendRedirect(oauthRequest.getLocationUri());
```

which triggers an exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
```

all advice gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

Google retired OpenID 2.0 on 20th April. See http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/reminder-to-migrate-to-oauth-20-or.html

Comment: It was because of this retirement that I migrated the code to use OAuth2.  The OAuth2 authentication worked fine prior to the 20th April.  I am concerned that it was still dependent on something which was deprecated but I cannot see what that might be.

Comment: I suggest try to obtain an http trace of what is happening, otherwise you're reliant on folks who know what oltu is doing internally.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @PetroKorienev the essential part is "google retired openid 2.0 on 20th April" which is why this isn't a link-only answer

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think i have understood what's going on.  It is related to the OpenID retirement, but somewhat obliquely

In my code:

```
OAuthClientRequest oauthRequest = OAuthClientRequest
  .authorizationLocation(discovery.getAuthzEndpoint())
```

is using an internal 'discovery' module which is trying to source information in a way which has been deprecated as part of the turn off of OpenID

the preferred Oltu way appears to be

```
OAuthClientRequest oauthRequest = OAuthClientRequest
    .authorizationProvider(OAuthProviderType.GOOGLE)
```

which works much better

rtm: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/OAuth+2.0+Client+Quickstart